# Dynamics CRM Dialog hangs/freezes when called via script

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

when dialog process is called from a script that is embedded on a ribbon button, The dialog freezes and enter into a not responding state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that When calling the dialog via script check the ObjectId Guid that it passes. If the provided Guid does not exist on CRM Database the dialog will hang without giving any error. This may happen if you want to create a dialog that do not need a entity record to run against. In this type of case you just want an inactive record to appointed as ObjectId.

```
function CallDialog()
{
  var clientId = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
  var url = clientId + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=%7b460ACCDC-701C-4947-8E72-CDE2C53807FC%7d&EntityName=EntityName&ObjectId=%7b115fbb02-b5a5-e711-8122-005056b32967%7d";
  window.open(url,"", "width=700,height=600");
}
```

Comment: Pls add screenshot & explain it better so that if someone face the same issue in future, they will find your answer helpful..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I added a screen shot of the script

Comment: I don't have a screenshot UI freezing now. It's just only spinning wheel on the web page.